# Parsing embedded JSON out of a CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm receiving tab delimited files with embedded JSON data in one of the columns. My goal is to split the columns, then do some work to process the JSON. 
When I try to use the built-in Ruby CSV library (with Ruby 2.2.3) I get the following error:

```
Illegal quoting in line 1. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
```

Here's an minimalist example that helps demonstrate the problem. The following lines work fine:

```
puts 'red,"blue",green'.parse_csv
puts 'red,{blue},green'.parse_csv
```

But this line produces the MalformedCSVError message:

```
puts 'red,{"blue"},green'.parse_csv
```

Any idea how I can parse that file and treat the middle value (which happens to be JSON) as a string literal?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You say you're receiving tab-delimited files with embedded JSON in them, but the examples you've shown are comma-delimited strings with no (valid) JSON. Please edit your question to include a real-world example of your input data and the actual code you're handling it with.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The embedded JSON isn't specific to the error. Any column data with curly braces next to double-quotes causes the same error. That's why I supplied a minimalist example that produces the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotes (`"`) is, by default, the character used to surround fields that may contain the CSV column delimiter (tab in your case).

You can get around this by setting the `:quote_char` option to something else, such as backticks or `\0`. Additionally, for tab-delimited data you're going to need to set `:col_sep`.

This should give you what you're looking for,

```rb
'red,{"blue"},green'.parse_csv(quote_char: '`')
=> ["red", "{\"blue\"}", "green"]

%Q{red\t{"blue"}\tgreen}.parse_csv(quote_char: '`', col_sep: "\t")
=> ["red", "{\"blue\"}", "green"]
```

Note that this breaks if either

- The JSON column contains tabs and not surrounded by `:quote_char` or
- The JSON data contains `:quote_char` (e.g. it contains a backtick).